# How to rename table using SSDT in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, local-database

I am using visual studio 2013 and trying to learn local database operations. I have created a database using VS and create tables. But I cannot rename table names. There is no such a option anywhere or I cannot see. I searched but find nothing.

Could anyone show me how to rename table using 'VISUAL STUDIO 2013 SSDT'

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538880/how-to-change-the-table-name-in-visual-studio-2013-in-design-mode

Comment: I know but I am looking for GUI solution

Comment: The other question's accepted answer does not answer the question. Question reasked to hopefully get an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open the table, highlight the table name in the T-SQL portion of the window, click the SQL menu, then choose Refactor and Rename.  You probably want to preview changes while you're at it to see what will be affected.

Comment: There is no `SQL` menu.

Comment: There have been a couple of changes to the interface. However, if I open a table and select a column, I do see a "SQL" menu with a "Refactor" option under that. I can also right-click the column and get a Refactor option.  Ctrl+R,R is the shortcut key that should be bound to a refactor/rename action. If none of those are working, your SSDT may need to be re-installed or updated.