# Renaming a table on Visual Studio SSTD project always crates a new table.

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on a project on Visual Studio 2013 and I am trying to script our database out. Everything is so fine but when I am trying rename a table, It creates another after publishing. 
I just want to rename it without create any other table.

So, Is there any option in Visual studio to rename table or other objects without creating another ?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename table using SSDT in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577669/how-to-rename-table-using-ssdt-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 3):

You need to right click the table and choose refactor—> rename so it adds the rename operation to the refactorlog.xml