# Visual Studio 2015 how to change table name?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I made a table in my database, and I don't know how to change it's name. Could somebody help me?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw5xhetd.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538880/how-to-change-the-table-name-in-visual-studio-2013-in-design-mode

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the latest works for me.